# Axios post call not handling expired token response ReactJS and ASP.NET Core 6 API

Tags: c#, reactjs, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am making post requests using Axios from my reactJS app to the asp.net core 6.0 API endpoint and passing a JWT Bearer token in the header as well. If the token is expired then the server returns 401. But the Axios goes to catch statement where  **error.response** is undefined. It does not handle a proper normal response. Please advise.

[image]

[image]

Client Code:

```
async function postData(endPoint, payload, isSecured = false) {
  try {
    const token = isSecured ? localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') : ''
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    }

    if (token && isSecured) {
      headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    }

    const response = await axios.post(endPoint, payload, { headers })
    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.error('Error Response:', error.response)
      throw error.response
    } else {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      **console.error('Error:', error.message)**
      throw error
    }
  }
}
```

Server-side code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"))
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });

        builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

Comment: When a 401 Unauthorized error occurs due to an expired token, Axios throws an error without populating the `error.response` object. In order to  to handle 401 responses specifically, you can use the `validateStatus` option.

`axios.post(endPoint, payload, {
  headers,
  validateStatus: (status) => status !== 401
})
.then(...)
.catch(...);`

Comment: Same issue. Did not work 

 axios
    .post(endPoint, payload, {
      headers,
      validateStatus: (status) => status !== 401 && status !== 403,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      throw error
    })

Comment: I was using JwtBearerEvents. I removed it and implemented a custom authorization attribute and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response, glad to know that you were able to resolve the issue.